# Uploading video to vimeo in ionic angular

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic-native

I want an example which explains me how can upload a video from my ionic mobile app to vimeo video. I tried following the vimeo docs but couldn't understood the example and using it in angular.

Answer (score 0):

First of all , you'll need to create a php project and you can get what you need for from this link :
https://github.com/vimeo/vimeo.php

This php project will let you make all vimeo actions through api (post,replace,etc...).

After creating your php api, now you can do normal httpclient requests to this api for uploading video or doing any crud action made in the php api .